# Azure Logic App Custom Connector Icon

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Is there any way that I could update the default icon of the custom connector logic app in Azure?
[custom connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnLII.png)

Comment: Are you the author of the said custom connector you're trying to change the icon for?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

In section 1. General of the Custom Connector configuration, there is the option to upload an icon.

This option is always available so you can update the image any time.

Comment: I am new to all these Azure components and to the company itself, so I am still learning. Would you mind helping me with how I can access the configuration of the custom connector in the logic app?. I tried to google but has no luck..

Comment: @Sid It's not in the Logic App itself.  In the Portal, you would select All service, then Logic Apps Custom Connectors.  You can add it to you Favorites by clicking the little star.

Comment: thanks, John, all great insights.. it appears for some reason our custom connectors are not showing up in the Logic App Custom Connectors services. Speaking with the concerned Developer, it seems like we have to get certified or something in order for our custom connector to appear in the Logic App Custom Connector space, I am going to drill down on that further offline. Thanks again for your answer.

Btw, I am not the author, I have joined this company as a product owner and was trying to figure out ways to improve the UI/UX of the custom connector.

Comment: Which connector are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can pretty much use an icon as per you need. All you need to do is add the `iconUri` param to the properties of your connector from code view.

Example :

```
"properties": {
        "description": My Custom Connector",
        "displayName": "[variables('my_connectorName')]",
        "iconUri": "[concat('https://', parameters('storageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net/icon/logo-icon.png')]",
              }
```